# How to iterate over object values and condtionally fire an event if all of them are filled?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a dynamically generated object in my component that looks like this:

```
currentObjectData: {
   data_type: ""
  }
```

Everytime a new component is generated, this object is populated with some more key/value pairs to be used on a later date, but the `data_type` is a dropdown with a few options that the user can select. What i want to achieve is, when there are multiple instances of said object and a button is clicked, i want to iterate over all objects, check for empty `data_type` and if there are any, trigger visual alert for the user. If there aren't any, i want to trigger an event. I've tried solutions along the lines of:

```
  Object.values(this.currentObjectData).forEach(objectData => {
    if (
      !this.objectData.data_type||
      this.objectData.data_type === ""
    ) {
      this.$v.$touch();
    } else {
      EventBus.$emit("allObjectsAreValidated");
    }
```

Or:

```
      Object.values((this.currentObjectData).forEach(value => {
        if (!value.includes("")) {
         EventBus.$emit("allObjectsAreValidated");
        }
      });
```

However, what i've managed to achieve is if in one of the objects `data_type` is not empty, the event fires. Can someone help me out with what am i doing wrong and how can i achieve the desired result? Thanks in advance!
P.S. The `data_type` is a `string`, and the flow is: The button that triggers this `method` is a parent component, and the idea is if the `method` emits back an event, to submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what @user1538301 answered, if you want to know which properties fail to fulfill the criteria is possible to use `Array::filter` the following way:

```
const missingProperties = Object.values(this.currentObjectData)
    .filter(data => objectData.report_type);

if(missingProperties.length > 1) {
    // Do something with the missing properties
} else {
    EventBus.$emit("allObjectsAreValidated");
}
```

Also a few things I noticed in the code:

1. `this.objectData` : I'm assuming your intention is not to use a variable from the object but rather the parameter of the anonymous function, so `objectData` would be the right variable.
2. `!this.objectData.report_type || this.objectData.report_type === ""` : An empty string is a *falsy* value so when evaluated as bool is equivalent to false. (More info: [FreeCodeCamp](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/javascript/falsy-values/##targetText=A%20falsy%20value%20is%20something,)%2C%20and%20false%20of%20course.))

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide adequate solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.prototype.every`

Try:

```js
const allObjectsMatch = Object.values(this.currentObjectData).every(
    value => /*return a boolean if they value matches*/
);
allObjectsMatch && EventBus.$emit("allObjectsAreValidated");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response sir, i'll give it a go!

Comment: Not a problem. We're here to support you!

Comment: You might also want to consider using `Array::filter` that way you can know which properties are empty.

Comment: @J.Pichardo Woah, that got complicated real fast! Mind posting an example solution that implements both solutions?

Comment: `const valuesThatMatch = Object.values(this.currentObjectData).filter(value => /*return a boolean if they value matches*/);`
Would give you the objects that match using `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: @user1538301 Thank you very much!